# How to make panels full height of parent div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Bootstrap 3 on a form with the following HTML, containing 4 panels with the same structure as the example below.

My problem here is that each panel contains a different and therefore appears with a different height. I tried adding `style="height:100%"` to them but that didn't change anything.

Can someone tell me how I can set them to always take the full height, independent of their content? Basically, what I am trying to achieve is to have all 4 panels take the same height as they appear in one row - **they only thing the differ is the paragraph with the variable text**, everything else is the same for all panels and takes the same height for each of them.

**Example panel:**

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="thumbnail thumbnail-hover">
                <div class="txtcntr" style="width:100%"><span>Placeholder for icon</span></div>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3 class="text-primary">Title</h3>
                        <p>Some variable text</p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-responsive" target="_self">View</a></p>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    // ...same structure for other panels...
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To adjust the height of your `thumbnail` use a fixed pixel height like `300px`.

```
.thumbnail {
    height: 300px;
}
```

The thumbnail class does not respond to percentage height changes.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was hoping I can avoid that somehow.

Comment: Check out the `panel` class - that might be better option over thumbnails: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels

Comment: Thanks - I'll go with the panel solution which seems to work here.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did: http://jsfiddle.net/o7p1jtjv/1/

By setting the `.row` to have a hidden overflow, and then giving each column `div` a `margin-bottom` equalling the `padding-bottom`, you force them to all be larger than the `.row`, but none of the overflowing content (extra `div` space) is shown.

For comparison, here is one without the extra rules: http://jsfiddle.net/o7p1jtjv/2/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.row
{
    overflow: hidden;
}

.row > div
{
    background: red;
    margin-bottom: -999999px;
    padding-bottom: 999999px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @Dan said, the panel class would be a better option. If you prefer not to use fixed height, you can use CSS flexbox like this..

http://www.bootply.com/IwBoyELqpx